# Delphi - How to delete all child components at runtime?

Tags: delphi, components, runtime, vcl

At design time, I create a TScrollBox which will be the parent of TLayouts created at runtime.
The Layouts will also contain Tlabels and Tedits like this:

```
var
  Layout1: TLayout;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Edit1: TEdit;
begin
  Layout1 := TLayout.Create(self);
  Layout1.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  Label1 := TLabel.Create(self);
  Label1.Parent := Layout1;
  Label1.Text := 'abc';
end;
```

Now I want to delete everything out like this procedure has never been called.

I have tried the following, but the program would just crash.

```
var
  i : integer;
  Item : TControl;
begin
  for i := 0 to Scrollbox1.ControlCount - 1 do  
  begin  
    Item := Scrollbox1.controls[i];
    Item.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Seeing the code you've posted in this and some other qs,you seem to be doing things like dynamically creating components which are normally completely unnecessary, and running into problems as a result.  If you would explain *why* you're creating these components, maybe readers could suggest other, less error-prone, ways of doing it.  E.g.  if this is to do with records read from a database, have you looked at the standard TDBCtrlGrid, which is basically a scrollbox that you can populate with DB-aware controls which get replicated for each row in its source dataset?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes I did look into details on TDBCtrlGrid and learned how to use it.  However, then I found out that it does not support mobile applications which is what I am working on.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Normally, I would delete my comment as not very relevant, but in this case I will leave it in case other readers have similar thoughts as I did.  Are your controls to allow the user to change the data or just for display?

Comment: My controls are to allow users to add/delete the data which gives me a lot of troubles... Sorry for all the questions that I have asked as I am new to delphi. This is just a little assignment I gave myself to learn how to write a mobile application that interacts with database.  Any response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

When you remove a control, the index of the ones behind it in the `control list` shifts down. I.e, you end up trying to access positions that do not exist.

You need to iterate the list downwards:

```
var
  i : integer;
  Item : TControl;
begin
  for i := (Scrollbox1.ControlCount - 1) downto 0 do  
  begin  
    Item := Scrollbox1.controls[i];
    Item.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Another way is to stay always at index 0, free its control and check that you still have controls to free:

```
var
  i : integer;
  Item : TControl;
begin
  while Scrollbox1.ControlCount > 0 do  
  begin  
    Item := Scrollbox1.controls[0];
    Item.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**

As @DavidHeffernan pointed out, there is *nested parentage* here. This means you should free your components from bottom up. One way to do it is by *recursion*.

Basically you would need a procedure to encapsulate the freeing of child controls. The code would be similar to following (please note this is just a small test I did and extra code may be required):

```
procedure freeChildControls(myControl : TControl; freeThisControl: boolean);
var
  i : integer;
  Item : TControl;
begin

  if Assigned(myControl) then
  begin
    for i := (myControl.ControlsCount - 1) downto 0 do
    begin
      Item := myControl.controls[i];
      if assigned(item) then
        freeChildControls(item, childShouldBeRemoved(item));
    end;

    if freeThisControl then
      FreeAndNil(myControl);
  end;
end;

function childShouldBeRemoved(child: TControl): boolean;
begin
  //consider whatever conditions you need
  //in my test I just checked for the child's name to be layout1 or label1
  Result := ...; 
end;
```

In order to free the `scrollbox1` child controls (but not itself) you would call it like this:

```
freeChildControls(scrollbox1, false);
```

Please note that I had to add the `childShouldBeRemoved` function in order to avoid this recursive function to free child controls of the `label` and `layout` that you should leave for their destructors to free.

One possible solution to implement this function would be to use an `object list` where you would add your created components, and then inside the function check if the passed child component has to be freed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just tried that but my program still crashes...any idea why??

Comment: When I run debugger, it shows 
"Project xxx.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0080b8b7: read of address 0x00000014'. Process xxx.exe (3484)

Comment: @AlvinLIn - That's a typical message for trying to access a method on a nil object. I would add a debugmessage telling you what control is getting freed and work from there. Probably the control being freed is doing a call on an unassigned childobject.

Comment: @Guillem There's nested parentage here. Recursion, or equivalent, is needed.

Comment: @Alvin There's no point asking us to debug fragments. Show a complete program. Why make it hard for us? Do you want help or not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am sorry that I didn't try to make it hard for you . I just thought it might be better that I pinpoint out the exact question that I had, so I wrote out this little fragments.  The actual program may take some time to go through...but here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kmlaor8jqrzb6f/Stock_2.rar
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Never mind. If I can't see the program, I cannot help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for the hint. I missed it when I answered first. I will update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Also be aware that this is an FMX project

Answer (score 3):

If you create components at runtime - use parent control as parameter of the constructor. Like `Label1 := TLabel.Create(Layout1);` - so that the parent is also the owner. When you destroy `Layout1` the `Label1` also will be destroyed.

Comment: There is some problems with understanding what is `parent` and what is `owner`. `parent` is the 'surface' where control shown. `owner` is the 'owner' :-)

Comment: `Label1` will be destroyed regardless (I also made that mistake and deleted my answer). `TControl.SetParent` causes `AParent.InsertControl(Self);` and the Parent *will* destroy it's child controls.